# PHP Codeigniter controllers and models filenames issue

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I have an CodeIgniter project, everything was fine when I worked on my local machine.
When I have uploaded the project to server suddenly controllers stopped working except the default controller. I have burned a few hours of searching the problem and have found that my controllers and models does not works because their file name was not with capital letter.

Example:

```
controllers/test.php - does not works
controllers/Test.php - works
```

The same is with models, I think that it is configuration issue of apache or something.

I have :

```
Ubuntu 14.04
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2014 16:36:58) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

Any ideas?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind : do you develop on Windows (eg. with WAMP) and have a Linux server? We've had that problem a few times because Windows doesn't care about case.

Comment: As I wrote, I have Ubuntu 14.04(Linux)

Comment: ubuntu as local machine? @AlexShuraits

Comment: Ubuntu on digitalocean, if it is helpfull. My local is OsX, but it does not matter. I have the same boilerplate that works fine on all servers I have worked with (CentOs,Debian, also on Windows). The problem, I think, is Ubuntu or version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a configuration issue. It's not an issue at all - just how most Linux file systems work.

Under Windows, and depending on an install-time configuration, on Mac OSX too, there's no distinction between 'test.php' and 'Test.php' - it's the same file.
With UNIX-style file systems on the other hand, you can have *both* 'test.php' and 'Test.php' in the same directory.

It might've worked for you under CentOS and Debian in the past, but that's because you've used older versions of CodeIgniter, which used to look for all-lowercase file names.

CodeIgniter 3.0-dev, which you are using now, requires that all class filenames start with a capital letter. This is explained in the upgrade instructions.